# How do I view the connections an OpenVPN client is making via the tunnel?

Tags: openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN. I've successfully gotten a client going through the VPN. What I'd like to do now is monitor the connections a client is making.

I was able to follow the instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/a/976226/36175) and get a management console going. But this only tells me what clients are connected, and their IP. It doesn't tell me the connections that that client itself is making that are exiting the tunnel.

How can I view these outgoing connections?

Comment: Same way you would see the connections on any other type of network interface?  tcpdump, iftop, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is basically as @Zoredache said: after the tunnel, the machine with the vpn server will make the same connections the client would've.

In my case I was further relaying the output of the tunnel through a proxy, so that wouldn't have worked... but the proxy itself outputted the outgoing connections it made, and I was able to see it there.